# User Control Form Click event not clicking on label C#

Tags: c#, windows, user-controls

I have a problem with User form `Click` that I am trying to make in C# using a `usercontrol`.
It consists of a `picturebox` and a `label`. I want to call the `click` event  but the picturebox and the label don't do anything when I click them. Only the background area of the `usercontrol` does what I want it to do. Any ideas?

here's my code

```
for (int i = 0; i < listitems2.Length; i++)
{
    listitems2[i] = new declined();

    //adding sample data to each dynamic user
    listitems2[i].dicon = dicon[i];
    listitems2[i].did = did[i];
    listitems2[i].dname = dname[i];

    //adding data to flow layout panel
    flowLayoutPanel2.Controls.Add(listitems2[i]);

    // below line will assing this (usercontrolclick) event to every user control created dynamically
    listitems2[i].Click += new System.EventHandler(this.UserControl_Click);
            
}
```

for click function

```
void UserControl_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    string ctrlName = ((UserControl)sender).Name;

    applicable obj = (applicable)sender;
    studid.Text = obj.id;
    studname.Text = obj.name;
    pictureBox1.Image = obj.icon;
}
```

Comment: you have to add same handler on both pictureBox and label. Because clicking on label isn't clicking on form, so form's onClick event is not registered

Comment: but i'm trying to click user control from main form where i cannot call picture box id. Kindly can u please elaborate in code?

Answer (score 1):

You added `OnClick` handler to your `UserControl`, so only clicks made on `UserControl` will be registered. To enable `Click` event for all the controls on your form, you need to add your click handler to all other controls.

But, according to your code, you're adding click handling on form where your control is located. In this case, you cannot register clicks on control from "outside" (you can by making `Label` and `PictureBox` controls public and adding handlers for their `OnClick` events but that is wrong way to do it)

My suggestion is to make custom event on your form and raise it on `Form`, `Label` and `PictureBox` click, and then make handler for that event on form which holds your `UserControl`.

Something like this:

```
//make custom eventHandler on your UserControl
[Browsable(true)]
public event EventHandler UserControlClicked;

//constructor
public UserControl1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    //after intialize compoment add same handler for all three controls
    this.Click += ControlClicked;
    this.pictureBox1.Click += ControlClicked;
    this.label1.Click += ControlClicked;
}

//this method will "catch" all clicks
private void ControlClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //raise event
    UserControlClicked?.Invoke(this, e);
}
```

and on form where your custom control is, add handler for UserControlClicked (maybe with cast, I don't know what listItems2[i] contains):

```
listitems2[i].UserControlClicked+= new System.EventHandler(this.UserControl_Click);
```

or maybe like this (with casting)

```
(listitems2[i] as UserControl1).UserControlClicked+= new System.EventHandler(this.UserControl_Click);
```

and handle the rest in your `UserControl_Click` method like before